# How to make navbar-links fill out 100% of the width of a page

Tags: css, width, nav, spacing

Here's my struggle. So I've been wondering how I could make the navbar-links fill out 100% of the nav. So that they have an equal amount of spacing and the font-size will decrease if more links were added - this way it will always fill out 100%.

As it is now, I cannot seem to achieve this. I've only got a set padding, but I've tried doing stuff like:

```
display: block;
float: left;
width: 100%;
```

but it's giving me all kind of effects that doesn't work at all :S

Anyone able to help me out on this?

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iuItp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove width from #main-navigation and add with to #main-navigation li with a value equal to the 100/the_numberof_elements_in_the list. Your css should be:

```
#main-navigation {
    height: 54px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#main-navigation ul {
    height: 54px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#main-navigation li {
    font-size: 1.0em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}
```

This way you'll have your nav occupying all the available width, but your font-size will not automatically resize. You'll should change it also in function of the number of elements (similar the way you have to do to the li's width). If your are generating this list dynamically at server side, you could do the same with the css and then calculate the right values for these two attributes. If your are using ajax to populate the list, you could do change the attributes with javascript.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems like a good way to do it, only problem is that I won't know how many menu-items will go in the nav, as that is up to the client when I hand in the wordpress installation. Is there no other way to make this work? Also, I think I did have to specify a width seeing that my sidebar is in the way.. Here's a codepen of the whole of it in comparison to the sidebar and content: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eDufF

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do this with a pure css approach. If are willing to use CSS3r, maybe it's possible to achieve this result with calculations, but they have a very poor browser support.

Comment: Here is a solution using JQuery. You can add elements to the list and everything will be resized accordingly. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KvnpA

Comment: Thanks Saul. This is really helpful, especially because I'm not familiar with JQuery at all. Is it just my browser though, or does the list items padding half for every item? Like the spacing gets smaller and smaller?

Comment: Actually, this Jquery script you gave me works great when combined with the display: table on the parent and display:table-cell on the children like @mno4k answered. Thanks to both of you I finally figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

A way of doing this is using `display: table` on the parent and `display:table-cell` on the children. I believe it won't work on some versions of IE (of course). [Here's](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ifnht) an exaple

Comment: This worked pretty well and did what I asked. Thanks for taking the time to tell me :) The only problem with this solution appears if I add more list-items than the set width can handle. I do believe that is because I've set a font-size and padding for the texts. So I guess I'd have to use Javascript to set some conditions like Saul showed me, but there is some problems with that solution as well, hehe..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `nav` tag instead and treat it as table. Treat the `<ul>` tag as table-row and `<li>` tag as table-cell. Ex:

```
nav{
 display: table;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%

}
nav ul{
 display: table-row;
}

nav ul li {
 display: table-cell;
}
```

This will stretch the contents of `<li>` 100%

I learnt it from the following link: http://www.darkstardesign.com/darkstar-blog/2012/11/27/stretching-horizontal-navigation-menus-to-the-full-width-of-a-layout/